# Trading in the stock market, anyone else think this is kinda fishy?

Tags: trading

I set random alerts and it seems that the price never ends up triggering the alert. This doesnt only just happen once but many times. Im thinking the alerts are most likely sent to a third party.
What are your thoughts? What are the chances the price literally just hovers over the alert price?

[image]

Comment: Not sure what I am looking at? Stock markets are 99% unpredictable. How many alerts did you set? How long did you wait? Why do you think the third party cares more about your alerts than about my alerts? What if I set an alert above yours, and it busted right through mine?

Answer (score 4):

A price alert has no effect whatsoever on market trading.  No one is  interested in your need to be notified that price has reached a certain level.

It's not much  different than setting your alarm clock to beep at a certain time.  When the number is reached, the alert triggers with the only difference being that share price may never hit the number.